# Style of textbox in Kendo Grid ASP.NET MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to show values in percentage in a column of kendo Grid (MVC). For ex if user types in 22 I want to show as 22%. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use a template column like explained [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-customize-the-way-a-property-is-displayed-in-a-grid-bound-column) in the documentation.

e.g.

```
ClientTemplate("#=kendo.format('{0:p}', myFieldName)#")
```

Comment: column.Bound(p => p.NAVPercent).Title("% of net asset value").ClientTemplate("#=kendo.format('{0:p}', NAVPercent)#").Width(75); still not getting % with value